# Is there a better way to change out a templateUrl in directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I have two directives, the functionality is identical the only differences is the template that is being shown. Is there a way to dynamically change the template?

This is what I came up with. Is there a cleaner way?

```
.directive('tileResource', function ($state) {
  return changeTemplate($state, 'ng-library/templates/tile_view.tpl.html'); 
})

.directive('listResource', function ($state) {   
  return changeTemplate($state, 'ng-library/templates/list_view.tpl.html'); 
})


function changeTemplate($state, template) {
  return {
    scope: {
      'resource': '='
    },
    templateUrl: template,
    link: function (scope) {.... // cool code   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Personally I find your solution suitable. However you might wish to read the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#template-expanding-directive) about defining `templateUrl` as a function

Comment: The issue I have I with using the templateUrl as a function is then I would have to define some sort of API on the elem the directive is declared on to specify where to find the template. And who ever uses the directives in the future would have to use. I would rather avoid that.

Comment: well definitely you would have to let the directive know which template to use. But you don't need API, just will pass mode like `my-resource="tile"` and internally define which template to use based on mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a refactoring of your existing code that does the same thing, but I think is clearer in its intentions.

```
createListDirective('listResource', 'ng-library/templates/list_view.tpl.html'); 
createListDirective('tileResource', 'ng-library/templates/tile_view.tpl.html'); 


function createListDirective(name, template) {
    angular.module('moduleName').directive(name, function ($state) {   
      return {
        scope: {
          'resource': '='
        },
        templateUrl: template,
        link: function (scope) {.... // cool code   }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `angular.directive`? It should be `angular.module("something").directive`

Answer (score 1):

Overall idea is fine, but current implementation doesn't look very clean because of dupe dependency arguments, you will also have problems with accessing the function from other modules.

It would be better like this, so you could make full use of Angular DI.

```
app.factory('baseDirectiveFactory', function (someDirectiveDependency) {
  return function (templateUrl) {
    return {
      templateUrl: templateUrl,
      controller: function () {
        // ...
      }      
    };
  }
})

app.directive('someDirective', function (baseDirectiveFactory) {;
  return baseDirectiveFactory('someTemplate');
});
```

Though I prefer to keep it closer to OOP approach with mixins:

```
app.factory('baseDirectiveService', function (someDirectiveDependency) {
  return {
    controller: function () {
      // ...
    }
  };
});


app.directive('someDirective', function (baseDirectiveService) {
  return angular.extend({}, baseDirectiveService, {
    templateUrl: '...'
  });
})
```

You can also extend the existing directive directly. Angular treats a directive as a service under the hood which contains an array of DDOs, you need the first (and only) DDO if there are no directive name collisions:

```
app.directive('baseDirective', function (someDirectiveDependency) {
  return {
    controller: function () {
      // ...
    }
  };
})

app.directive('someDirective', function (baseDirectiveDirective) {
  return angular.extend({}, baseDirectiveDirective[0], {
    templateUrl: '...',
    // the inheritance of 'name' property may cause problems later
    name: undefined
  });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create function like this:

```
function changeTemplate($state, template) {
  return {
    scope: {
      'resource': '=',
      'template': '='
    },
    template: '<div ng-include="{{template}}"></div>',
    link: function (scope) {.... // cool code   }
  }
}
```

And just change template argument on parent scope.